# Image plotly to HTML in Python

Tags: python, html, pandas

I can plot the graph. My code is like this:

```
plt.savefig('test3.png')
fig.write_html("test3.html")
```

> AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'write_html

I need to convert the image to html and then put it in my email.

I was hoping to save the image and then convert it to html, as I am developing an automatic email in python and the idea is to use the graphic and place it in the email.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.io.write_html.html), it should be done like this:

```py
plotly.io.write_html(fig, "test3.html")
```

I have not tested it, but I think it should work.